# Can I reinstall ubuntu-desktop while using Unity 7?

Tags: command-line, unity, 16.10

I want to reinstall Unity while using it.

Can I do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`?

Is this possible or is it going to crash?

Comment: If `ubuntu-desktop` is already installed, that command will only reinstall `ubuntu-desktop`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Nothing bad happens if I do that with `ubuntu-mate-desktop` on Ubuntu MATE ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i deleted the Gnome 3 desktop enviroment, i wanna reinstall Unity just in case it screwed somthing up.

Comment: @Zanna I'm using Unity 7 on Ubuntu 16.10, not MATE (and yes, i tried the Desktop Enviroment but i hated it)

Comment: Ok. As @Zanna said, you can run it safely. Possibly it will pull a few recommends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, you can safely upgrade a package while using it. There is no guarantee to that, though... it really depends on the individual package.

The reason why it often works is how Linux handles open files: When a process opens a file, it receives a handle to that file (a "file descriptor") which it uses to read/write data. During the update process, a file might get deleted or replaced even though some processes still hold file descriptors to it. In these cases, the file system keeps the old file around, and the running processes can continue using it. The file is removed only once every process closes their file descriptors.

This means that a process (such as Unity) will keep running even if their binary is replaced or removed. However, when the process opens new files, it could get "confused" about their content, and arbitrarily bad things (such as crashes) can happen.